# Removing all occurrences of a character from a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, function, char

My assignment says I should write a function called removeChar that;

1. Takes 4 inputs: an integer num, a string str, a string s and a character c, but does not return
   anything.
2. Finds the number of all the occurrences of c in s (both capital and lower case (hint: you may
   use ASCII codes for comparison)) and saves it in num
3. Copies the trimmed string in str
4. Write in the same file a main() function containing a series of tests to showcase the correct
   behavior of removeChar ().

But all printing operations should be done from the main() function. I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
string removeChar(int num, string s, string str, char c);
int main()
{
    string s = "asdfasdf";
    s = removeChar(1, "a", "hello", 'h');
    cout << s;
}
string removeChar(int num, string s, string str, char c)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (int(s.at(i)) == int(c))
            num = int(c);
    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), (char)num), str.end());
    return str;
}
```

It doesn't work, and even if it did, I need to have a void function.

Comment: Hint: output parameters must be references.

Comment: @Marque Phoenix This function declaration  string removeChar(int num, string s, string str, char c); does not make any sense. For example the parameter num is not used in the function.

Comment: If you need a function not returning anything, then the result needs to be a parameter (reference) too.

Comment: Finding the number of all occurrences of `c` in `s` likely means "how many times does `c` appear in `s`", not "what is the numerical value of the character `c`"

Comment: On requirement number 3, what is the "trimmed string"?

Comment: If str is "hello", the trimmed string would be "ello".

Comment: I don't know why the num is a parameter in the function but that is the assignment I got.

Comment: The explanations with numbers I made are the actual assignment that I got.

Comment: `num` and `str` are likely meant to be references. You declare them in `main`, pass them into your function, and any changes in the function act on the original object.

Comment: If you don't know what references are, consult your professor or your text book. I don't say that to be short or mean, I say that because this website doesn't have the best format for acting as a tutorial. Plus, if your question is "what is a reference in c++" that question likely already has an answer on here and you should search for it before asking it.

Comment: Why does it even get downvoted, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No I know it I just didn't think of it. Thanks.

Comment: @Marque Phoenix It is because the description of the assignment and the provided code do not make any sense. For example in the assignment there is written that  the function shall return nothing but your function declaration has the return type string.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes I know it doesn't but that is the description I got and that's why I asked it here.

Comment: `(hint: you may use ASCII codes for comparison))` just that tells me the person setting this question is incompetent.

Comment: @john Why do you think so? What should have been done?

Comment: You compare characters, if two characters are the same they compare equal. ASCII has nothing to do with it. And in any case not every platform uses ASCII, ASCII is not part of the C++ language. For instance your code above `if (int(s.at(i)) == int(c))` can be rewritten simply as `if (s.at(i) == c)`, there's no need to convert to int (which is where I think the misunderstanding about ASCII is coming from).

Comment: @john But are ASCII codes same for upper and lower case characters? I thought that's why he hinted at ASCII.

Comment: @MarquePhoenix No, that's not true, upper and lower case characters have different ASCII values, for instance A is 65 and a is 97. Maybe I was being a little critical, but really ASCII is not an issue when comparing characters, plus a few other strange things in your assignment didn't give me a good impression of your prefessor.

Comment: @john I'm not disagreeing, I just want to learn the right way to do it. What I tried to do is I take a character input like 'a' and by doing (int)a-32, I can remove both uppercase and lowercase letters from the string. So the user only has to type one character. Do you think it's a good way to do something like this?

Comment: @MarquePhoenix `(int)a - 32` only works if you are using ASCII (which you probably are, but as I said, not every C++ environment uses ASCII). The correct way to convert to upper case is to use the `toupper` function declared in header `<cctype>`. That works whatever character encoding your system is using. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the description of the assignment correctly,
then you need something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

void removeChar( std::string::size_type &n, std::string &str, const std::string &s, char c )
{
    str.clear();

    c = std::toupper( ( unsigned char )c );

    auto equal_to_c = [&c]( const auto &item )
    {
        return std::toupper( ( unsigned char )item ) == c;
    };

    std::remove_copy_if( std::begin( s ), std::end( s ),
                         std::back_inserter( str ),
                         equal_to_c );

    n = s.size() - str.size();                                   
}

int main() 
{
    std::string::size_type n = 0;
    std::string str;

    removeChar( n, str, "This is a silly assignment", 's' );

    std::cout << "n = " << n << ", str = " << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is:

```
n = 5, str = Thi i a illy aignment
```

Comment: Nice, now he will have more problems explaining the solution, than he usually had with his initial problem :-)

Comment: You could fix the string "assignment" ... there is an "m" too much.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Thanks. I removed the redundant letter.

Comment: @YesThatIsMyName Yes actually I don't even know what auto is, but I'll try to learn I guess.